# CSS image in div ignoring padding

Tags: html, css, image, background, background-image

I have an image inside a `div` and want the image to have some space from the borders of the `div` it's contained in. I have tried adding padding but the image still fills the whole `div` and seems to ignore the padding values I've added.

This is what the image looks like:

[image]

```css
#railwayblock {
  height: 500px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-color: green;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/800");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="railwayblock"></div>
```

I want it to have some space from the borders of the div that it's contained in as I have mentioned before.

Comment: It may have something to do with you setting the background-image of the div. Is there a reason you can't put an image element inside of the div instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`background-size:cover;` will make the background image always cover *everything*, *including* the padding space.

You can either use a regular image (i.e. `<img>` tag) instead of the background image as child of a parent element which has the padding, or you can use a background image in a div and wrap a parent element around that one which has the padding. In this case you need `height` settings for both, with the height of the inner element being smaller by the amount of the top and bottom padding.

Answer (score 0):

What if you tried using an HTML `img` tag instead of background?

For example,

```html
<body>
<div id="railwayblock">
  <img src='animated_train.jpg'></img>
</div>
</body>
```

```css
#railwayblock {
  height: 500px;
  border: 10px solid green;
  padding: 0 50px;
}
#railwayblock > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover
}
```